# How to use <FontFamily> to reference resource fonts？

Tags: c#, wpf

I added a font file to the project, and I want to put it in the resource dictionary.

But it can't be identified correctly. I think it can only recognize the font name.

- code

  `<FontFamily x:Key="anticon-uri">pack://application:,,,/Ant.WPF;component/Resources/#anticon</FontFamily>`

I've tried the following method, it's OK.

````
```
<Style x:Key="anticon" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Ant.WPF;component/Resources/#anticon" />
    </Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource anticon}"  TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    </Style>
```
````

**Do you have a better way?**

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.

syntax： `<FontFamily x:Key="anticon-uri">ResourceFile FontName</FontFamily>`

Example：

`<FontFamily x:Key="anticon-uri">pack://application:,,,/Ant.WPF;component/Resources/#anticon anticon</FontFamily>`

Comment: Loading fonts with a relative path ( that's a relative path in your example ) causes a memory leak. You need an absolute path to avoid that. Or install the font.